# Executing minimum distance between random samples in python

Tags: python, point, latitude-longitude, shapely, sampling

Right now, my code finds random points within an area and appends them to a variable that I can export as a file. Next, I want to make sure that no two points are within 100 meters of each other.

I've seen through other posts that I could add some sort of minimum distance variable, but I'm not sure how to execute that. Does anyone know how I'd adjust this code to make sure each random point is not within 100 meters of another one?

```
all_points = []
...

 # find area bounds
    bounds = aoi_geom.bounds
    logger.debug(bounds)
    xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = bounds

    xext = xmax - xmin
    yext = ymax - ymin

    points = []
    while len(points) < int(pts):
        # generate a random x and y
        x = xmin + random.random() * xext
        y = ymin + random.random() * yext
        p = Point(x, y)
        if aoi_geom.contains(p): # check if point is inside geometry
            for point in all_points:
                    points.append(p)
                    all_points.append(p)
    gs = gpd.GeoSeries(points)
```

Comment: An approach is as you create a point, create a buffer with a 100m diameter then check if that intersects any points, if it does then reject the random coordinates. You will need to deal with the scenario that the space you create your random points within  might "fill up" and it becomes impossible to insert a new point.